# Customizing Notifications in XP

Tags: windows-xp, notifications, sp3

Under taskbar properties in Windows XP SP3, there is an option to customize the notification area. However, when I'm trying to customize the past items, I see that there are nearly 100 different items, the majority of them are programs which have been uninstalled ages ago.

How can I eliminate all the past items that are not installed on my computer and keep the ones that are installed on my computer?

Screenie: (there are nearly 100 items, mostly nonrelevant, in the Past Items section)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click **Start** > **Run** >  type `regedit` and click **OK**

Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\TrayNotify`

Delete the `IconStreams` and `PastIconsStream` values.

Open Task Manager, click **Processes** tab, select Explorer.exe, then right click and **End Process**.

Still in Task Manager, click **File**, click **New Task**, type `explorer`, then click **OK**.

Comment: Probably safer than killing and restarting explorer is just to log off and back on, or reboot.

Comment: Logging off and on didn't work. Will try reboot now.

Comment: Reboot didn't work... BUT killing & restarting explorer DID work! Thanks alot! Very clean now :P

Comment: you're more than welcome :)